# How can I store an animated sequence of images on the Apple Watch using WKInterfaceDevice

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I have put a sequence of images in the (images.xcassets) of my WatchKit App, and I wrote some code to launch the animation.

Everything is working fine , but I read in (https://developer.apple.com/watchkit/tips/) and many blogs that you should store image sequences on Apple Watch, in order to reduce load times.

- How can I store all the images in the Apple Watch storage ?
- How can I use WKInterfaceDevice to store the images on the Apple Watch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the images are already included in the image catalog in your WatchKit app bundle you don't need to do anything else. Caching and the like is only for images your transfer from the phone. Note that this applies only to the catalog in the app bundle, not the extension bundle.